Is it ethical to edit grammar, spelling, and wording errors in survey questions after the survey has been administered, prior to publication?
Is it ethical to copyedit grammar, spelling, and wording errors in survey questions after the survey has been administered, prior to publication, if the changes do not change the meaning of the question or the answers?
I am an academic editor working with PhD students and faculty. I often find grammar, spelling, and wording errors in surveys during the final copyedit prior to submission of a dissertation or journal paper, and I wonder if I have any leeway for correcting those errors. Here I'm only talking about errors that don't impact respondents' understanding of a question or how they would answer them. An example: "In your opinion, how much is Kamala Harris qualified become president of United States?" That question has two grammar errors and one style error. Changing the question to "In your opinion, to what extent is Kamala Harris qualified to become president of the United States?" would not change participants' understanding of it.
This question is important due to the large number of nonnative English researchers and less-skilled PhD students.
It would be unusual for a PhD student or scholar to seek copyediting of survey questions prior to posting them online. The result is that papers being edited for publication often contain spelling, grammar, and wording errors in survey questions. Is it an ethical violation to correct those errors?
A thornier, related problem is when the responses to survey questions don't work grammatically with the question, or vice versa. Example: To what extent do you agree with each of the following statements? Answers: Yes, No, Uncertain. You could correct that by changing the question to "Do you agree . . . " This is a more difficult ethical question because it increasingly leaves the ethical decision to the editor, which could be risky.
Is this a black-and-white issue, meaning one should never change anything in survey questions after administration? Or is it OK to correct errors (a) that would embarrass the author and diminish an otherwise good study and (b) when the changes would make no difference in how respondents understood and answered the questions?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The question asks about a case where:

Changing the question ... would not change participants' understanding of it.

What is important is not just the understanding but specifically what the influence is on the data and whether changing the question would change the data. This is something that must be supported by empirical evidence for your specific case, and it's very difficult to show that something doesn't do anything to understanding, at best you would argue that the difference in wording does not change responses by more than some threshold amount, and it would require a large sample using the same question worded multiple ways.
Wording that is unclear or contains grammatical errors may create a higher burden on participants: it distracts them, and this can change their responses. It may also affect the likelihood of people completing the survey. So, if you are reporting results of a survey, you must report exactly what the survey was, errors and all, for an audience to get a fair look at it.
Some references on the effects of wording on survey responses:
Fowler Jr, F. J. (1992). How unclear terms affect survey data. Public Opinion Quarterly, 56(2), 218-231.
Ganassali, S. (2008, March). The influence of the design of web survey questionnaires on the quality of responses. In Survey research methods (Vol. 2, No. 1, pp. 21-32).
Lenzner, T., Kaczmirek, L., & Lenzner, A. (2010). Cognitive burden of survey questions and response times: A psycholinguistic experiment. Applied cognitive psychology, 24(7), 1003-1020.
Lenzner, T. (2012). Effects of survey question comprehensibility on response quality. Field Methods, 24(4), 409-428.

I'm not involved at all with surveys and such, and never have been, and even I thought this was "survey methods 101" stuff. (I like @Buffy's ironic comment above, by the way!)

I've accepted this answer because it appears that everyone is in agreement that this really is a black and white question and the answer is simply NO, it is not ethical to make any changes whatsoever to survey questions, even to correct spelling. Thank you for weighing in on this.

I wonder: What do researchers do when the survey is conducted in a different language than the report of the results? Do they publish both the original questions (so we know what the respondents actually answered) and a translation (so the readers can understand)?

@Eggy: Are you familiar with the meta marking "[sic]"?

@Barmar Hopefully someone can give a more authoritative answer, but in some studies funded by the South Korean government with official translations, they do provide both.

@Barmar I would expect both in any paper I am reading.

Agree absolutely. For some respondents (like me) I'm going to give low-quality answers to low-quality questions, and that will affect the outcome.

@MichaelKay Yes, if I see a survey that doesn't capitalize "France" (to steal an example above), I'm probably exiting your survey.

The survey has many more readers than the paper in which the results are reported, so if you didn't bother to proofread the questions, why bother to fix them in the publication? It's clearly a black-and-white question, the survey should be published verbatim with all its mistakes and typos included.

It's dishonest to claim your survey questions were different than what they actually were.  It doesn't matter what those differences are; using one survey in your study and then presenting a different survey in your report is lying.

I'm surprised that people do view this as 100% black and white and are quick to cast judgment on the paper writer. Not all paper writers have mastery of the English language and resources available to them to correct all errors in their writing prior to submitting a paper for publication, e.g. researchers in India, Asia, etc. I hope to hear some more nuanced views from people who have experience with this issue.

That is because it is really not a nuanced question. The argument you make when doing empirical research is: "this is how I have looked around, and this is what I saw". Details matter, because that is how we can later compare results from different studies and understand differences. This is how progress is made in the empirical sciences.

@Eggy the non mastery off the English language is an issue here. The non master might think the change does not matter but a native speaker might spot a difference. Or the other way round non native speakers might read the original question in a different way to a native speaker. For an example see UK ONS Census question on gender https://www.theguardian.com/society/2023/nov/08/census-records-trans-population-in-england-and-wales-but-accuracy-is-doubted

@Eggy: This isn’t an issue of “casting judgement” on the writer for errors in their English — that would indeed be both scientifically unwarranted and somewhat inequitable, and is certainly a more nuanced question.  The black-and-white issue is about accurate reporting: whatever wording was used in the survey should be reproduced accurately in the report.

Shouldn't "different" be "the same"?

@Eggy: I mean, if someone is writing a survey in a language they don't master, they have to know they're taking on a more challenging task, and reach out to a resource that can help them avoid mistakes at this critical point. Compare to someone running lab equipment with signs and manual in an unfamiliar language.

@Barmar: The reader will think the survey questions are the same as what's presented in the report.  Actually they were different from what's in the report.  Turn that around: what's claimed in the report is different from what the questions actually were.  Different is the word that belongs in that sentence, and in the similarly structured one beginning David's answer.

@BenVoigt But they're saying what's DIShonest. It would be truthful to say that the questions are different from the actual survey. It's dishonest to claim that they're the same.

@Barmar The structure of the first sentence in the answer may be a little complicated, but it is essentially saying that it is dishonest to misrepresent the survey questions. It talks about the reported (claimed) survey questions and the actual administered questions. If those are different from each other, it is indeed dishonest because there is an implication that they are the same. Technically, you could write a truthful "here are some survey questions but they're different from the ones we administered" but that would be a useless way to describe the methodology.

@Anyon Now I see how to parse it.

@mmmmmm the UK census question on gender really was worded in a fundamentally different way, i.e. asking if someone is "trans" versus whether they identify as a gender other than that registered at birth. A person might reasonably (or unreasonably!) define "trans" as meaning something other than having a gender other than that registered at birth, or might consider "trans" to be a voluntary label that a person can accept or reject regardless of gender facts. No amount of grammatical corrections will transform one of those questions to the other, so the comparison doesn't seem fair.

@Eggy I find it absolutely appropriate to cast judgement on a paper writer who deliberately misrepresents the work they did by revising their methodology after the experiment is already done! This has nothing at all to do with the quality of the writing.

When writing up a paper, you should be reporting the methods as accurately as possible. If the survey was worded in a specific way, you should report that wording in the paper. Describing your methods inaccurately to avoid embarrassment is not really acceptable in my view. You can't prove that the changes made no difference to how the respondents understood and answered the questions.
Additionally, you say it would be unusual for a PhD student to seek edits on survey questions before posting them online - I strongly disagree! English is my first language and I would still go through at least one round of feedback on any questionnaire I developed before using it to collect data.

Its pretty much like asking if its OK to change data points after the experiment is over...

@Dee. Again, I want to distinguish between feedback on the content and organization of a survey and final copyediting of a paper as the last step before submitting it to a journal.

@Eggy What people are trying to say is, why are these errors noticed in the final steps of the writing process and not before the survey is administered? If the feedback process before the survey doesn't catch them, that feedback process isn't good enough. However you seem to already have a feedback mechanism in place that can catch such errors, so it seems weird that you only want to apply it too late.

So view the comments you have been getting from this point of view: the answer to your literal question is a clear, straightforward, resounding "no", but people are worried how such a question could come up in the first place.

@Noiralef. As an editor, I am the last person in the process. I have to deal with the realities and imperfections of the process. In the US, the quality of PhD programs varies from lower-skilled faculty and students at online universities to higher-skilled people at top-tier universities. Graduate students report lack of detailed supervision. Professors report lack of time for detailed supervision. I see problems in the planning and wording of research questions constantly in my work across the spectrum from lower- to top-tier institutions, in the papers of both students and faculty.

@Eggy: As an editor, it is your duty to ensure that any problems which may have affected the results are accurately and completely disclosed to the reader. To do otherwise would be to mislead the reader about the quality of the research. If this makes your students or professors look bad, then all you can do is advise them to consult you (or someone else) before the survey has been given, so that you can correct the problems before they affect the results.

@Kevin "As an editor, it is your duty to ensure that any problems which may have affected the results are accurately and completely disclosed to the reader. " Really no, that's neither my duty nor my area of authority. I do point these problems out to authors, but they're free to accept or reject my feedback. I'm not a journal editor. I'm a freelance academic editor.

@Eggy: I don't know the precise division of labor between you and the authors, but at the very least, it is your duty to avoid hiding such problems from the reader in your own editing. If the authors choose to mislead the reader, that may not be your responsibility, but when you actively help them do it, you commit misconduct.

As a short addition to Bryan Krause's answer, even if you're assuming that the formatting of your survey questions did not affect the understanding of the questions, not only it can distract respondents and increase non-response, but also prompt them not to take the survey seriously and to give poor-quality answers. So the quality of the answers resulting from the badly formatted questions should be questioned, and you should definitely report the survey questions as they were asked.
As your question is whether it would be a violation of ethics not to report the problem, besides the other answers in this thread, you can certainly refer to ethical guidelines relevant to your discipline if you need references. It might be useful if the journal where you intend to publish insists that you don't disclose the original version of the survey (but in this case, I'd be wary of publishing a paper in such a journal in the first place). For instance, the American Sociological Association's Code of Ethics say:

Sociologists take particular care to state all relevant qualifications
on the findings and interpretation of their research. Sociologists
also disclose underlying assumptions, theories, methods, measures, and
research designs that might bear upon findings and interpretations of
their work.

The American Statistical Association's ethical guidelines state:

[...]
The ethical statistical practitioner seeks to understand and mitigate
known or suspected limitations, defects, or biases in the data or
methods and communicates potential impacts on the interpretation,
conclusions, recommendations, decisions, or other results of
statistical practices.
The ethical statistical practitioner:

Communicates data sources and fitness for use, including data generation and collection processes and known biases. [...]



To generalize the issue at hand, methodological details should be reported as accurately as possible in all circumstances. Publishing an edited survey would be no different from making a different type of experimental mistake like using the wrong reagent or setting the wrong algorithmic parameter and deliberately mis-reporting the design to match what you meant to do. Without evidence, you shouldn't conclude that the difference doesn't matter anyway and take the decision away from the reader.
What you could do is publish the intended design alongside the actually implemented one, and make some argument that the difference was minimal, or hypothesize about the differences. If the experimental flaw was significant enough that it may have affected the outcome in a major way (for example if the survey question is later determined to be easily misinterpreted), this should be directly addressed as a limitation of the design. Publishing a corrected version of the design might not be particularly useful for survey questions, but it might be helpful in other fields where the experimental design might be replicated more closely.

I should have greatly simplified my question by asking, "Is it okay to change 'france' to 'France' in a survey question when editing a paper for publication? I'd be interested in opinions on that.

@Eggy I dont think it is ok to change france to France.

Thank you, lalala.I do want to hear people's opinion on france/.France, but it would also be good to have an authoritative source on this.

@Eggy This can be incorrect to assume that respondents have the same attitude as you relative to spelling mistakes. Taking your specific example, there are people who are sticklers for spelling, or nationalists/regionalists who would interpret it as indifference or contempt toward their home place, influencing in turn their attitude toward the survey. Even if you could measure the effect of the formatting issues rather than guessing from your personal experience (i.e. by testing adequately two versions of the survey) and find the effect is trivial, you should still report the two versions.

For example, French people might feel insulted by the use of lowercase “french” and some will change their answer to what they feel annoys you most. In other words, some answer will have a lower percentage than the  same question with “French”. If I know the original question, I can take this effect into account. If you change the question you report then I will misinterpret the results.

Don't change it.  There is no legitimate reason to say you used method X when you actually used method Y, even if X and Y are very close and unlikely to have any difference. It's hard to argue that there is so little difference that X and Y are equivalent, yet different enough that you don't want to simply state you did Y.
